# Rails: How to call up Today.now in the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How would one write correctly Today.now in a controller

*payments_controller.rb:*

```
def create
current_user.update(
      recent_subscription_pymt_date: Today.now
    )
end
```

The above gives the error:

> uninitialized constant Userr::Today

I tried creating a method in the user model

```
      user.rb (user model)
      def today_date
        self.recent_subscription_pymt_date == Today.now
      end
```

*payments_controller.rb:*

```
current_user.update(
      recent_subscription_pymt_date: current_user.today_date
    )
end
```

But no luck, your advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not relevant to your question but your method in the user model would not work - you used `==` which is for comparison - you wanted to use `=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in `Today` class, but you can try `Date`:

```
Date.today
```

or `DateTime`:

```
DateTime.now
```

Comment: Thank You SOOOOOO MUCH! Thank you! @potashin